Why did David measure Moab with a cord?
In 2 Samuel 8:2 David defeated Moab and "measured them off with a cord" such that 2/3rds would be killed and 1/3 allowed to live.
I would like to understand the purpose of measuring them with a cord. If the goal was to kill 2/3rds of the people, that could have been done by counting.
Standard Mikraot Gedolot commentaries I have consulted speak about degrading the Moabites, however that seems to apply to making them lie and the ground, not the use of the cord. I would like to understand why David measured them with a cord specifically.

There is a heavily midrashic explanation in the book "The Juggler and the King" by R' Aharon Feldman, ch. 14 The midpoint of the World, especially the section 14.9. The book expounds the peirush on several aggados by the Vilna Gaon. (please see the book for many additional details)
The discussion starts with the aggadeta Bechoros 8b:

They (the Elders of Athens) said to him: Build us a house in the air of the world. Rabbi Yehoshua uttered a Name of God and hovered between the sky and the earth. He said to them: Bring up to me bricks and mortar and I will build you a house here. They asked him: Where is the center of the world? Rabbi Yehoshua raised his finger and said to them: Here. They said to him: And who says that you are correct? He said to them: Bring ropes and measure.

The point here is that the existence of humans is tied to gradual recognition of G-d, as at the end of the days the world will be full of wisdom "as water cover the sea" (Yeshayahu 11:9). Gemara Sanhedrin 97a-b splits the timing of the history into 3 eras:

The school of Eliyahu taught: Six thousand years is the duration of the world. Two thousand of the six thousand years are characterized by chaos; two thousand years are characterized by Torah, from the era of the Patriarchs until the end of the mishnaic period; and two thousand years are the period of the coming of the Messiah. That is the course that history was to take, but due to our many sins, the Messiah did not come after four thousand years passed, and furthermore, the years that elapsed since then, which were to have been the messianic era, have elapsed.

Even though the Jews had not merited the Moshiyach's coming, nevertheless the Era of Moshiyach arrived at its proper time. At "the midpoint of the world" G-d began turning the wheels of history to ensure the ultimate arrival of the scion of David.
The connection to the question of the OP, comes with the help of the vision of Zechariyah 13:8-9:

Throughout the land — declares  G-D — Two-thirds shall perish, shall die,
and one-third of it shall survive. That third I will put into the fire, And I will smelt them as one smelts silver And test them as one tests gold. They will invoke Me by name, And I will respond to them. I will declare, “You are My people,” And they will declare, “ The ETERNAL is our G-d!”

This prophecy is a link between R' Yehoshua's idea to refute the words of the Elders of Athens and the words Sh'muel B 8:2 noted by the OP as the significant part. To quote R' Feldman from the book:

The ultimate aim of G-d's judgement is not cruelty but bringing man to recognize Him and thereby gain eternal life. The recognition of G-d, then is the essence of human life and its consummation. During the first two-thirds of world history G-d waited for men to exercise free choice, to abolish evil from their live and reach the essence. When mankind as a whole failed, that essence was denied it and the Jewish people toook on the task. When they too failed, He withheld His revelation from them; He destroyed their land and sent them into exile. But in the last third - after 4000 years from the Creation - He manipulates history so as to give quintessential life even to those who do not deserve it. Even if the Jews do not choose to seek their G-d and recognize his rulership, he will nevertheless take them by the hand and lead them to this recognition. Worthy or not, they must be redeemed, or else the ultimate aim of Creation would never be realized.
The ropes of David are the measure of human history. The two-thirds of world history which did not choose to recognize G-d's dominion refused to choose life. But the last third will be directed to the eternal life by a Providence which will lead the Jews step by step to the recognition of their G-d.
What is the basis of your assertion, asked the Elders (of Athens) that "here", in the last third of human history, G-d's mercy is at work and we are in the era of Moshiyach? Rabbi Yehoshua answered, "Remember the ropes of king David and you will learn the ways by which G-d directs His world." They teach us that G-d will never abandon His world, that ultimately the good for which  G-d created it will be realized.

In other words, David, as a prototypical Moshiyach, hinted in this punishment the ultimate punishment that Hashem will bring upon the world in exact form from every person, as stated in Zechariya.

It is worthwhile mentioning that although, indeed, the מצודות translates חבל as rope, the רד"ק brings the תרגום who translates חבל as “lots” (as in יעקב חבל נחלתו), which, of course, makes his action easier to understand. As to the lying on the floor, he did that as a way to disgrace them, as a punishment for having killed his father, mother and all his brothers. The מפרשים bring מדרשים that דוד wanted to punish the Moabites for a singularly vicious and vindictive crime which they had committed. When דוד was fleeing from שאול, he had asked the Moabite king to allow דוד’s parents and brothers to remain with him and be protected by him. Mindful of his own descent from מואב through his ancestress רות, he had thought that his family would be in safe hands. The Moabite king agreed to extend his protection to דוד's family but subsequently murdered them all with the exception of one of דוד's brothers who managed to escape. דוד, then, was avenging the murder of his family.
